# How to read formatted file without delimiters in matlab?

Tags: matlab, sqlite

I have a file with rows like this (first two rows with 25 columns in each):

> ```
>   1921.300       .      .    <  0.030     .         .     .       .     .     550        1.6   1 Mrr1922  Jm   5  
>   1973.220    158.     3.       0.240    0.002      .     .      1.5   0.5    620        5.1   1 Lab1974  S    4
> ```

and description (first 4 columns as example):

```
term       columns   format   description   
date       008-017   f10.5    Observation date, in years.    
tflag      019-019   a1       Flag for theta (position angle) measure. Flags 
                          include:
                          : = uncertain/estimated (old code U)
                          L = originally published as nf, sp, etc. 
                              (old code L)
                          Q = quadrant flipped 180deg from published value 
                              (old code Q)
                          V = measure is vector separation along this angle 
                              vector (previously used only in 
                              interferometric catalog)  
theta      020-026   f7.3     position angle, in degrees  
terr       028-033   f6.3     published formal theta error, in degrees  

etc.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to read this file in Matlab? I have no delimiters (only positions and formats). The basic idea is to read this file in my SQLite database but (if I right) SQLite works only with delimiters.

Comment: how exactly do you want the final data represented in matlab after it is done reading in and processing the files?  E.g., cell array?  Also, it looks like there may be missing values based on your example 2 rows.  Are there missing/empty values, and if so, how are they encoded?

Comment: Yes @user2566092 ! There are missing values in the file. I don't know how are they coded. I need to read this file to add delimiters and to write csv file with delimiters. The basic idea is to read file above to my SQLite database but as I realize SQLite can not do this without delimiters.

Comment: What about [textscan](http://goo.gl/Y6E1E) or similar functions in matlab?

Comment: @Marcin , I do not know what to use, textscan, sscanf, fscanf or something else. And what is the difference between these functions?

Comment: I've solved my problem with help of interactive IMPORT in Matlab IDE.